# Error: Google authorization for R Studio "sign in temporarily disabled"

Tags: r, google-api

I've been using my Google API credentials to access Googlesheets through R for a while now. Today, I made the mistake of running a script that calls from a different google account (my work account) and now I have this error: 
[image]

When I clicked through, it says that I only need verification if I'm creating a user-facing app (I'm not). What I'm doing is reading and writing Google Sheet data. I've tried recreating my OAuth key, I've tried changing the project scopes (it's the //auth/drive scope that's throwing the wrench in things).

I'm not actually a developer, I'm a data analyst and use R code for a fairly small scope (Google Sheets, a few data resources like the NOAA, Google Analytics, and social platforms). I use this for my side business and need to get it going again before I get any orders. Since I'm not a developer, I'm really at a bit of a loss here. Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this would help but I had the same problem to share a shiny app to draw numbers and store the value of the pixels in a google sheet. What worked for me was to create a `token.rds` file which stored the information to authenticate each rstudio session.

#### How to create the `token.rds` file

I recommend you to read [this tutorial](https://gargle.r-lib.org/articles/get-api-credentials.html#get-a-googlecloud-platform-project) if you have not created the OAuth 2.0 Client ID. If you have created an OAuth 2.0 Client ID for your google account and you have the public and secret key, run the following code:

```
library(googlesheets)
your_gs_app <- gs_auth(key = "782348718282-bgaocvueexiq9qbackboidne19aaa5v9dg.apps.googleusercontent",
                    secret = "gFMmSoWPVPLu2EmdBLOBuSZs")
```

This would require you to verify the app in the same webpage that you have posted in the image. Click on Advanced > Go to *application-name* (unsafe) and grant the permissions in the next  few windows. Once you have granted all the permissions, close the navegator and go back to RStudio to create the `token.rds` file by running:

```
saveRDS(your_gs_app, file = "token.rds")
```

Now that you have created the file to authenticate the R session, you can authenticate any R session in other computers by running:

```
googlesheets::gs_auth(token = "token.rds")
```

with the `token.rds` file in the working directory (obviously)

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is great, thank you! I've been trying the first step (creating the token) and that hadn't worked, but saving and then running it did. Appreciate the help!